# windows docker on vmwarevsphere

Tags: docker, vmware, docker-machine, vsphere, docker-for-windows

we use VMWare vSphere for VMs in our company.

To automatically create docker hosts we use one simple command:

```
docker-machine --driver vmwarevsphere .... vm params(cpu,memory,network,name, etc)
```

It automatically creates new VM machine in our VM cluster, installs docker and then we add it to swarm or create new.

Right now I need to create windows docker hosts to run windows containers. 
Docker-machine installs boot2docker.iso after creating VM. 
But instead I need VM with microsoft servercore or nano.
How do I do it?

Thanks a lot.
Anton

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows machine with Docker for Windows installed you could run the following command to pull the official images for server or nanoserver

docker pull microsoft/nanoserver
or
docker pull microsoft/windowsservercore

I'm not exactly sure how you're automating this - are you using a dockerfile or docker compose?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about setting up the Windows host that runs Docker engine?  If so, Docker for Windows CE is meant to be desktop software so not recommended for server side workload.  Also, Windows EE Server requires Windows Server 2016 or later.  If you would really like to use Windows server core mode, Windows Server 1709 offers that.  Still, it quite bit new, so you should not set high expectations just yet.

As per the instruction to install the engine, MS has this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-server

Or, equivalent one from Docker here.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/docker-ee/

Answer (score -1):

you are talking about hosting a windows container on VMware vSphere? I don't think this is possible right now, may be in the future. I have no documentation or link to verify my answer but in our company we have a similar situation and use vSphere for VMs and Linux container and  Hyper-V in parallel for VMs and windows container.